# Plotly:How to create subplots with python?

Tags: python, plotly

I am wondering what is best practice to create subplots using Python Plotly. Is it to use `plotly.express` or the `standard plotly.graph_objects`?

I'm trying to create a figure with two subplots, which are stacked bar charts. The following code doesn't work. I didn't find anything useful in the official documentation. The classic Titanic dataset was imported as `train_df` here.

```
import plotly.express as px

train_df['Survived'] = train_df['Survived'].astype('category')
fig1 = px.bar(train_df, x="Pclass", y="Age", color='Survived')
fig2 = px.bar(train_df, x="Sex", y="Age", color='Survived')

trace1 = fig1['data'][0]
trace2 = fig2['data'][0]

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, shared_xaxes=False)
fig.add_trace(trace1, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace2, row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

I got the following figure:

[image]

What I expect is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Hi! and welcome to the forum! There are surprisingly many aspects of your short snippet that leaves me a bit puzzled. First of all, what are you aiming to show in `fig1`? It seems to me that what you would get here is the sum of the age for each class, split by whether or not they survived. Or am I missing something here? Maybe that's not really important, and you would just like to know how to do these things?

Comment: @WangShengdao How did my suggestion work out for you?

Comment: Hi @vestland! Thanks for your reply. I'm currently exploring plotly to replace the seaborn I've been using. To be more clear, I'd like to know how to create subplots with stacked bar charts, as well as when to use plotly.express and plotly.graph_objects. Your solution does help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping that the existing answer suits your needs, but I'd just like to note that the statement

> it's not possible to subplot stakedbar (because stacked bar are in facted figures and not traces

is not entirely correct. It's possible to build a plotly subplot figure using stacked bar charts as long as you put it together correctly using `add_trace()` and `go.Bar()`. And this also answers your question regarding:

> I am wondering what is best practice to create subplots using Python Plotly. Is it to use plotly.express or the standard plotly.graph_objects?

Use `plotly.express` ff you find a `px` approach that suits your needs. And like in your case where you `do not` find it; build your own subplots using `plotly.graphobjects`.

Below is an example that will show you one such possible approach using the `titanic` dataset. Note that the column names are noe the same as yours since there are no capital letters. The essence of this approav is that you use `go.Bar()` for each trace, and specify where to put those traces using the `row` and `col` arguments in `go.Bar()`. If you assign multiple traces to the same `row` and `col`, you will get stacked bar chart subplots if you specify `barmode='stack'` in `fig.update_layout(). Using`px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[i]` will let you assign colors from the standard plotly color cycle sequentially.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

url = "https://raw.github.com/mattdelhey/kaggle-titanic/master/Data/train.csv"
titanic = pd.read_csv(url)
#titanic.info()
train_df=titanic
train_df

# data for fig 1
df1=titanic.groupby(['sex', 'pclass'])['survived'].aggregate('mean').unstack()

# plotly setup for fig
fig = make_subplots(2,1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df1.columns.astype('category'), y=df1.loc['female'],
                     name='female',
                     marker_color = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[0]),
    row=1, col=1)


fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df1.columns.astype('category'), y=df1.loc['male'],
                     name='male',
                     marker_color = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[1]),
    row=1, col=1)


# data for plot 2
age = pd.cut(titanic['age'], [0, 18, 80])
df2 = titanic.pivot_table('survived', [age], 'pclass')
groups=['(0, 18]', '(18, 80]']

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df2.columns, y=df2.iloc[0],
                     name=groups[0],
                     marker_color = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[3]),
    row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df2.columns, y=df2.iloc[1],
                     name=groups[1],
                     marker_color = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[4]),
    row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(title=dict(text='Titanic survivors by sex and age group'), barmode='stack', xaxis = dict(tickvals= df1.columns))
fig.show()

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't know a single subplot can take multiple traces. This is helpful. I provided an alternative solution as below.

Comment: @WangShenghao Happy to help! Thank you for accepting my answer although you came up with a solution yourself (+1)

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, it's not possible to subplot stakedbar (because stacked bar are in facted figures and not traces)...

On behalf of fig.show(), you can put to check if the html file is okay for you (The plots are unfortunately one under the other...) :

```
with open('p_graph.html', 'a') as f:
    f.write(fig1.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn',default_height=500))
    f.write(fig2.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn',default_height=500))
```

try the code below to check if the html file generate can be okay for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#Remove the .astype('category') to easily 
#train_df['Survived'] = train_df['Survived'].astype('category')
Pclass_pivot=pd.pivot_table(train_df,values='Age',index='Pclass',
                   columns='Survived',aggfunc=lambda x: len(x))
Sex_pivot=pd.pivot_table(train_df,values='Age',index='Sex',
                   columns='Survived',aggfunc=lambda x: len(x))

fig1 = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Survived', x=Pclass_pivot.index.values, y=Pclass_pivot[1]),
    go.Bar(name='NotSurvived', x=Pclass_pivot.index.values, y=Pclass_pivot[0])])

# Change the bar mode
fig1.update_layout(barmode='stack')


fig2 = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Survived', x=Sex_pivot.index.values, y=Sex_pivot[1]),
    go.Bar(name='NotSurvived', x=Sex_pivot.index.values, y=Sex_pivot[0])])
# Change the bar mode
fig2.update_layout(barmode='stack')

with open('p_graph.html', 'a') as f:
    f.write(fig1.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn',default_height=500))
    f.write(fig2.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn',default_height=500))
```

Comment: Hi I hope to generate the plot in a notebook environment, but it's good to know how to generate plots in html. Thanks for your advice anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to generate the subplots using the ***add_bar*** function.

**Code:**

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# plotly can only support one legend per graph at the moment.
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, cols=2,
    subplot_titles=("Pclass vs. Survived", "Sex vs. Survived")
)
fig.add_bar(
    x=train_df[train_df.Survived == 0].Pclass.value_counts().index,
    y=train_df[train_df.Survived == 0].Pclass.value_counts().values,
    text=train_df[train_df.Survived == 0].Pclass.value_counts().values,
    textposition='auto',
    name='Survived = 0',
    row=1, col=1
)
fig.add_bar(
    x=train_df[train_df.Survived == 1].Pclass.value_counts().index,
    y=train_df[train_df.Survived == 1].Pclass.value_counts().values,
    text=train_df[train_df.Survived == 1].Pclass.value_counts().values,
    textposition='auto',
    name='Survived = 1',
    row=1, col=1
)
fig.add_bar(
    x=train_df[train_df.Survived == 0].Sex.value_counts().index,
    y=train_df[train_df.Survived == 0].Sex.value_counts().values,
    text=train_df[train_df.Survived == 0].Sex.value_counts().values,
    textposition='auto',
    marker_color='#636EFA',
    showlegend=False,
    row=1, col=2
)
fig.add_bar(
    x=train_df[train_df.Survived == 1].Sex.value_counts().index,
    y=train_df[train_df.Survived == 1].Sex.value_counts().values,
    text=train_df[train_df.Survived == 1].Sex.value_counts().values,
    textposition='auto',
    marker_color='#EF553B',
    showlegend=False,
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(
    barmode='stack',
    height=400, width=1200,
)
fig.update_xaxes(ticks="inside")
fig.update_yaxes(ticks="inside", col=1)
fig.show()
```

**Resulting plot:**
[image: Expected stacked bar charts generated using plotly]

Hope this is helpful to the newbies of plotly like me.